Cracking on rear tyre only (Specialized Armadillo Hemisphere)
I use a mountain bike with Specialized Armadillo Hemisphere trekking tyres for regular commuting, and recently noticed cracking around the tread features on the rear tyres (see photo); the front tyres look fine. Front and back tyres are the same age (about 3 years) and have experienced the same conditions (distance, weather, UV, storage, etc.) and don't have much tread wear, and the bike is garaged when not in use. Presumably, therefore, the damage to the rear tyre is due to differences in load and/or pressure.

The tyres are rated for 250-450 kPa (36-65 psi), and I have generally aimed to run the front tyre at 300 kPa (44 psi) and the rear at 320 kPa (46 psi). I weigh about 80 kg and usually carry about 5 kg in my backpack. Should I be using higher pressure on the back? I'm also mindful that they lose a significant amount of pressure due to disconnecting the pump.

I wouldn't completely rule out different conditions.  I know my back tyre gets more sunlight (and more rain) parked outside work than my front tyre, because I always park the same way round and the shade is partial.  The front mudguard also shades the tyre a bit better when parked there.  And work is where it's most likely to be parked during daylight

46psi/3bar seems about right for a 38mm tyre. On my daily I usually start at 3.5bar and I notice the difference at about 2bar and top it up. Your presumaption about the different load between front and back causing the cracks in the rear and not in the front is correct. Your tyres do not lose a significant amount of pressure when you disconnect the pump.
But the issue with the cracking isn't incorrect use, it's just that three years is a long time for a bike tyre. The rubber degrades and hardens over time even if it is shielded from direct sunlight. The Armadillo is a very heavy tyre so I suspect it has quite thick side walls, which will not be very pliable once they start to harden, making them even more prone to cracking.

It might well just be a combination of age and load - I've read that rear tyres need replacing perhaps three times as often as front ones, which might not be solely due to tread wear. I'll try increasing the pressure somewhat while deflating my expectations!

It's also possible the cracks can be caused by ozone, especially if you're storing your bicycle near any source of ozone such as an electric motor.
Per Wikipedia's "Ozone cracking" article:

Cracks can be formed in many different elastomers by ozone attack, and the characteristic form of attack of vulnerable rubbers is known as ozone cracking. The problem was formerly very common, especially in tires, but is now rarely seen in those products owing to preventive measures.

And later:

Tiny traces of ozone in the air will attack double bonds in rubber chains, with natural rubber, polybutadiene, styrene-butadiene rubber and nitrile rubber being most sensitive to degradation. Every repeat unit in the first three materials has a double bond, so every unit can be degraded by ozone. Nitrile rubber is a copolymer of butadiene and acrylonitrile units, but the proportion of acrylonitrile is usually lower than butadiene, so attack occurs. Butyl rubber is more resistant but still has a small number of double bonds in its chains, so attack is possible. Exposed surfaces are attacked first, the density of cracks varying with ozone gas concentration. The higher the concentration, the greater the number of cracks formed.
Ozone-resistant elastomers include EPDM, fluoroelastomers like Viton and polychloroprene rubbers like Neoprene. Attack is less likely because double bonds form a very small proportion of the chains, and with the latter, the chlorination reduces the electron density in the double bonds, therefore lowering their propensity to react with ozone. Silicone rubber, Hypalon and polyurethanes are also ozone-resistant.

While newer tires can be formulated to resist ozone cracking, if your bicycle spends literally most of several years in a closed closet or small room that has a source of ozone, there will likely be some effect on the tires.

How does this explain the difference between front and rear tire?

@ojs The bicycle could be stored such that the rear tire is closer to the ozone source.

It's assuming a lot of detail that isn't really supported by the question.

Interesting thought - the garage at home is shared with a petrol car that gets driven once or twice a week and a desiccant-based dehumidifier. The dehu actually has an ionizer mode, which I've seldom used but will avoid in future. Recently (only in the last few months) the bike has been stored against a wall with its weight on the rear wheel, which might be a factor.

...stored overnight when not in use, that is - not continuously for months.
